# Bitnami Wordpress > bnconfig.exe doesn't start

Tags: wordpress, apache, configuration, windows-10, bitnami

I installed Bitnami Wordpress some days ago, everything was fine until today : My webpage wouldn't launch. So I tried to launche Xampp through Bitnami configuration tool

**Path :**
..\Bitnami\wordpress-5.8.2-2\apps\wordpress\ **bnconfig.exe**

Double ticking on it spins the loading yet nothing launches even after restarting the computer / checking background apps.

What should I do ? Regards

Comment: Hello, Isn't there anyone to help ? Thanks

Comment: You gotta be way more specific and add screenshots.

Comment: Hello @jasie, I apologize for the late answer.

Comment: https://www.noelshack.com/2022-19-2-1652141209-1.png

I tried to launch bnconfig.exe since Apache launches on port 8080. So, I wished to change port through bnconfig.exe

I have the windows 10 loading wheel, the prompt to run bnconfig.exe then nothing happens. What should I do ? Regards